# With the implementation of the CORS security model will the cross-domain extension "permission" privilege be eliminated or absolete?

Tags: cross-domain-policy

I have referenced the link below but the answers provided are not conclusive.  If in fact the purpose of CORS from the website provider point of view is to restrict programmatic access to their webpage data then they will be reluctant to grant server side permission.  In this case I don't see how a local extension would override the permission from the server.

[Is CORS a secure way to do cross-domain AJAX requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4850702/is-cors-a-secure-way-to-do-cross-domain-ajax-requests)