# Posting data to different domain using PHP, AJAX don't work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, cors

I'd like to post data from `domain1.com` to `domain2.com` using AJAX, but my request fails.

Here's is my code on `domain1.com`:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'https://domain2.com/payment/api/server',
    crossDomain: true,
    data: {
            Name: $("#name").val().trim(), 
            Email: $("#email").val().trim()
          },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        alert('Success');
    },
    error: function (data) {
        alert('POST failed.');
    }
});
```

and here's my server side code on `domain2.com`:

```
switch ($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']) {
  case 'http://domain1.com/api/': case 'http://domain1.com/api/':
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: '.$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']);
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
    header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 1000');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Authorization, X-Requested-With');
  break;
}

$name = $_POST['Name'];

echo $name; // Just to check if I receive the value from index.php
```

Comment: The answer on the duplicate is outdated. Nowadays we have CORS: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636611/how-does-access-control-allow-origin-header-work

Comment: **Marked for reopening.* The OP asks about cross domain post using CORS. The other question and selected answer don't mention CORS.

Comment: @Jasny-ArnoldDaniels is there any wrong with the given code? please advise.

Answer (score 1):

You are checking if Origin HTTP header equals to `'http://domain1.com/api/'`. However, [MDN CORS docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Origin) say:

> The origin is a URI indicating the server from which the request initiated. It **does not include any path information**, but only the server name.

You have to remove the path from the string, i.e. it has to be `'http://domain1.com'`.

Corrected `server.php` code:

```
switch ($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']) {
  case 'http://domain1.com':
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: '.$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']);
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
    header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 1000');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Authorization, X-Requested-With');
  break;
}

$name = $_POST['Name'];

echo $name;
```

Answer (score -1):

As a side note: if you are using the "HTTP_ORIGIN" header to "secure" your requests, you should rethink it. Anyone can spoof this header and arbitrarily set the value. You are better off using some kind of key/secret to avoid unwanted requests. See: [Is CORS a secure way to do cross-domain AJAX requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4850702/is-cors-a-secure-way-to-do-cross-domain-ajax-requests)

Comment: You can't spoof Origin header using XMLHttpRequest or Fetch API.