# Laravel - Protect AJAX get calls

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, security, cross-site

I am building an application in Laravel with loads of AJAX calls. I have protected the POST, UPDATE calls with CSRF token in AJAX headers.

My question is is there a way to protect the GET ajax calls from cross-site access. For example I dont want users to type in the ajax call route and get a response, instead i want them redirected to 404 page.

Thanks

Comment: This is called CORS - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4850702/is-cors-a-secure-way-to-do-cross-domain-ajax-requests

Comment: If you really want something to be CSRF protected you should make it not a GET request. GET requests should not change the state and therefore should not need CSRF protection since nothing can be altered.

Comment: A 403 response would probably be more appropriate if access restriction is your goal.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using [Laravel Passport](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/passport) for this problem with the help of [this particular point from Laravel Passport](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/passport#consuming-your-api-with-javascript) to consume your API with JavaScript.