# Requests hit production Rails API despite Rack::Cors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, cors, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a Rails API and I have `Rack::Cors` setup in my `application.rb` to prevent requests from any origin other than `https://my-website.com` as:

```
config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
  allow do
    origins 'https://my-website.com'
    resource '*',
             headers: %w[Authorization],
             methods: %i[get post put delete options head],
             expose: %w[Authorization]
  end
end
```

Additionally I allow websocket connections as:

```
config.action_cable.url = %r{/wss:\/\/*/}
config.action_cable.allowed_request_origins = 'https://my-website.com'
```

And lastly I have a `status` checker for my `Application Load Balancer` and for that I allow http requests to `/status` as:

```
config.force_ssl = true
config.ssl_options = {
  hsts: { subdomains: true },
  redirect: { exclude: ->(request) { request.path =~ /status/ } }
 }
```

So as you can see every path except  `/status` should be `https` only but I am still getting errors such as below in my production error tracker:

```
#590 ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches [OPTIONS] "/"
```

In the details I get the source as:

[image: Production attempts]

How is it possible for someone to manage to reach my actual route when the origin is not added in my `CORS configuration`?

Comment: Someone could use not-a-browser to do HTTP request to your server.

Comment: Last line(`OPTIONS /`) is a pretty standard "CORS pre flight request" when someone visits `https://ip/`

Comment: @PavelMikhailyuk and the cors would allow a non-browser request to the server?

Comment: CORS is not a "protection of the server". It's just "advice" to the browsers.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4850702/is-cors-a-secure-way-to-do-cross-domain-ajax-requests

Comment: Thank you for the detailed information and the link. From the link you added it seems like there isn’t any way to prevent the requests themselves and the only thing I can do is to make sure all the relevant requests have authentication blocks in my code. Please let me know if my understanding here is incorrect and there is something I can do to prevent this

Comment: Yes, you are right: when you have a public endpoint, anyone can do request. Moreover, when you have a production app, you watch a lot of requests from bots, hackers etc in your logs every day. So, the only way is to implement authentication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Rack::Cors` only responds to `OPTIONS` request if request has `Access-Control-Request-Method` header, if someone issues that request without it - request will hit your regular routing.

Also note that CORS is only a method for browsers to allow cross-origin requests, anyone can use some non-browser script or tool to forge any requests they want.