# nestjs enableCors with health check

Tags: node.js, kubernetes, nestjs, health-check

My API cluster is under kubernetes.

```
    if (!configService.isProduction()) {
        app.enableCors();
    } else {
        const whitelist = ['https://sub. domain .com', 'https:// www.domain .com', 'undefined'];
        app.enableCors({
            origin: function (origin, callback) {
                if (whitelist.indexOf(origin) !== -1) {
                    console.log("allowed cors for:", origin)
                    callback(null, true)
                } else {
                    console.log("blocked cors for:", origin)
                    callback(new Error('Not allowed by CORS'))
                }
            },
            allowedHeaders: 'X-Requested-With, X-HTTP-Method-Override, Content-Type, Accept, Observe',
            methods: "GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,UPDATE,OPTIONS",
            credentials: true,
        });
    }
```

The problem here is when the deployment up Kubernetes try to run a health check and fails at **origin**, origin return as undefined.
Added to my whitelist undefined value, it didn't work.

What is the best way to limit access to my API?

Comment: rate limiting, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Origin headers can be faked in non-browser environments, so using CORS to try to prevent unauthorized access to your API is not a secure solution.

CORS is specifically meant to prevent browsers from making requests cross-domain to servers that do not have the appropriate CORS headers.  It's not designed to protect the server; it's designed to protect the browser and the user.

Assuming you're actually wanting to secure and authenticate your api, you have a couple easy options here:

1. Remove authentication for your health check endpoint (not recommended)
2. [Use HTTP headers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/#define-a-liveness-http-request) in your livenessProbe to authenticate Kubernetes:

Something like this should work.  Note that you could use any kind of authentication headers you want here.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  labels:
    test: liveness
  name: liveness-http
spec:
  containers:
  - name: liveness
    image: k8s.gcr.io/liveness
    args:
    - /server
    livenessProbe:
      httpGet:
        path: /healthz
        port: 8080
        # Add basic auth, or any other auth mechanism you want here:
        # Make sure to use your own user:password in Base64 if you copy/paste
        httpHeaders:
        - name: Authorization
          value: Basic dXNlcjpwYXNzd29yZA==
      initialDelaySeconds: 3
      periodSeconds: 3
```

There's other ways that you could achieve this, but without more information on the rest of your cluster it's hard to provide you with a better answer.

I would also highly recommend that you don't deny requests with the `origin` function.  Generally speaking, that's used to dynamically configure the CORS whitelist, and the error is used to signal that something went wrong while configuring it.  It gives a false sense of security, since the origin header can be spoofed by any non-browser request library.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29806023/8727490) is a great answer on CORS and what it's used for.

Comment: Thanks! why not to remove authentication for health check? why do I care if one tries to reach it ?